# receiving xml with value null when it's actually null

Tags: xml, jdbc, livecycle

I'm executing a stored procedure on sql server 2005 from livecycle es 8.2

the result return something like

```
<Table>
<Row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <EN_Cd>EN</EN_Cd>
    <FR_Cd>null</FR_Cd>
    <EN_Nm>English</EN_Nm>
    <FR_Nm>Anglais</FR_Nm>
    <EN_Shrt_Dscrptn>null</EN_Shrt_Dscrptn>
    <FR_Shrt_Dscrptn>null</FR_Shrt_Dscrptn>
</Row>
</Table>
```

I'm trying to figure out why the word "null" is put in the result.

Even with type xs:int it return the word "null"

is there something in the jdbc or livecycle that can fix this?

the stored procedure is a simple

```
   select id, en_cd, fr_cd, 
          en_nm, fr_nm, 
          en_shrt_dscrptn, fr_shrt_dscrptn 
   from language
```

fr_nm, en_shrt_dscrptn, fr_shrt_dscrptn are null in the database, they do not contain the value "null".

Comment: Please edit your post and add the query that produced this result.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, I updated my question

Comment: What is converting the query results to XML?

Comment: Had the same question but posted on Adobe forums. Here's the link http://forums.adobe.com/thread/721645?tstart=0.  Never really got a good answer other than speculation that the behaviour might change with JDBC/Datastore combo.  Basically, the XML just returns the value in the field, period.  I'd say the best bet is to XSLT the nulls into the correct XML xsi:nil="true", before it returns out of the workflow.

Comment: @Jim Garrison - LC has 'foundation' components that you configure through the IDE.  One of the 'foundation' components is a JDBC one, that contains what is called a 'Query Multiple Rows as XML'. It calls the datastore and then formats the results into an XML result. A good example of how it works, with a solution for transforming the results is here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/transforming_jdbc.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the coalesce() function to convert nulls to empty strings, like this:

```
select id, 
      coalesce(en_cd,''), 
      coalesce(fr_cd,''), 
      coalesce(en_nm,''), 
      coalesce(fr_nm,''),
      coalesce(en_shrt_dscrptn,''), 
      coalesce(fr_shrt_dscrptn,'') 
from language
```

Alternatively, you could investigate how the conversion to XML is happening, and see if there's a way to specify null-handling options there.

Comment: Yea unfortunately you have to wrap the columns with either coalesce or isnull in SQL. In Livecycle 9 if a column is null and you are using the Select single row component it will actually throw a SQL Exception.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a XSLT transformation for removing the NULL from the nodes content. check my questions for a further explanation on that